# Android cursor get next

Tags: java, android, database

i have this database printer in android.
[image]

```
Cursor curTAB = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  GPS_Values;", null);

Integer count = 0;
while (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
    String s_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
    String s_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
    String s_speed = curTAB.getString(5);
    count++;

    String next_speed = ???

}
curTAB.close();
myDataBase.close();
```

and i would like to know how to get the next speed in the loop?

Comment: what's the structure of your table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (curTAB.moveToNext()) {
    String s_latitude = curTAB.getString(1);
    String s_longitude = curTAB.getString(2);
    String s_speed = curTAB.getString(5);
    count++;
    int position = curTAB.getPosition();

    if(curTAB.moveToNext()) {
        String next_speed = curTAB.getString(5);
        curTAB.moveToPosition(position);
    }
}
```

should work, I'd say.

Comment: it works once. but i need it in every time when the count is increasing

Comment: You're welcome. You have to handle the last row a little bit different according to your business logic. For the last row there is obviously no next row.

Comment: can u help me a little? :)

Comment: Well, what do you want the next speed to be for the last row to be? 0? -1? Look at your table, for the last row there is no next row, so therefore there is no next speed.

Comment: I know my brain is to tired today(>8 hours programming), but can u help me in it with code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35614/discussion-between-mirco-widmer-and-david)

Comment: My Last question: how to get the position-1 value fdrom the database?

Comment: You have to move the curser back (curTab.moveToPrevious()), get the value, move the cursor one step ahead (curTab.moveToNext()) again.